# Navbar dissapears when view is displayed from segue

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a TableViewController that has an embedded NavigationController. There is also a ViewController to add new locations to the tableview.
This shows the relevant section of the Storyboard
[image]

When the user clicks a choose location there is a segue action through the NavigationController to the LocationChoiceTableViewController... a shortened version of the display is...
[image]

As you can see my navbar is showing with two buttons to add or edit the list. If a user clicks Add the segue action takes them to the AddLocationViewController...
[image]
The user adds details of the new location and clicks Add which has a segue action back to the LocationChoiceTableViewController passing back the values entered as a single concatenated string (newLocationtoPass)

The viewDidLoad in LocationChoiceTableViewController class has....

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultsController.tableView.dataSource = self
    self.resultsController.tableView.delegate = self


    if let savedLocations = defaults.objectForKey("locations") as? NSData {
        locations = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(savedLocations) as![String]
    }

    if newLocationtoPass != nil {
        // we have a new location passed via segue from AddNewLocationViewController

        //add new location to locations array and sort
        insertSorted(&locations, newItem: newLocationtoPass)
        // save location array to NSUserDefaults
        saveLocationArray()
    }

    self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: self.resultsController)
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true

}
```

Which if newLocationtoPass is not null will insert the value into the array (in the correct sorted position) and save the array to NSUserDefaults... All this works as shown in the screenshot below...
[image]

My problem is that I have lost my navbar with the edit/add buttons. I added the line `self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)` but the navbar does not show when returning from AddLocationViewController.

Any help in fixing this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed... I changed my Storyboard so that the segue actions from the Cancel and Add buttons on the AddLocationViewController went to the NavigationController and not the LocationChoiceTreeViewController.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try to write self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true) in viewWillAppear .. this may help you..

Comment: Sorry... no change to the way the views display